# Why is the correct way to toggle draggability in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is how I toggle between "draggable" and "not draggable".  Note `self.J` holds the correct jQuery object.

**draggable:**

```
self.J.logo_arcmarks.draggable('enable');
```

**not draggable:**

```
self.J.logo_arcmarks.draggable('disable');
self.J.logo_arcmarks.draggable('destroy'); // removes CSS from element
```

I am getting this error:

> [08:57:29.422] Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'enable' @

Click on the logo to enable and disable draggability and you will see the error in the console.

Reference

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write any code to start or stop the dragging.
Just call .draggable() on your object and you'll be able to drag it, and let go of it.

See this very basic example I've made: http://jsfiddle.net/fVAnB/

```
yourObject.draggable();
```

Comment: but I want to make it stop being draggable as well.

Comment: That initializes the "draggable" library. Calling it with 'enable' and 'disable' assumes you initialized it before, hence the error jQuery UI Draggable throws.

Comment: this, actually works, but does not explain why the other 8 or so elements did not need this fix.

Comment: If you need to initialize it but not enable it then you can use this: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-disabled Sidenote: there's absolutely no sane way for us to debug this thing running in arcjs.

Comment: @Sergui - what do you mean?  do you bite your thumb at me sir?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to initialize the draggable object

```
self.J.logo_arcmarks.draggable();
```

You should not have to pass an argument to enable a draggable object unless you've previously initialized and disabled one.